# Correct way to reopen TCP connection with PHP after remote party closes?

Tags: php, ios, tcp, apple-push-notifications

I'm having issues reopening a TCP socket connection after its remotely closed. Specifically this is for Apple Push Notification service - when Apple encounters a device token from you that pairs with a device that deleted your application they close the secure TCP socket to their push gateway. I need to immediately reopen this connection (or start a new one) when this issue occurs so I can continue sending notification to other users who still do have the app installed. I have some code using which I try to sort this out but it's freezing my entire Apache server and I have to restart manually to get things running again and I have no idea why. Below is the code with which I attempt to reopen a socket with Apple:

```
if($error_response == "InvalidToken"){
    $results .= "\ntried to restart";
    fclose($fp);
    usleep(20000);
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck_real.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', '****');
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
}
```

Comment: Sort of related; do you not get a notification when a device deletes your app, so you can prevent sending invalid tokens? And do you know exactly what code is freezing your server? I mean, on which call specifically?

Comment: Yes you do, separately - so, you setup a page like respond_to_deleted_tokens.php and Apple's servers make calls to that page with the tokens of the devices that deleted your app. But I don't want to rely solely on that since there might be cases when the notification doesn't go through for other reasons (not to mention I didn't implement a page like this yet so I already have deleted tokens that I didn't catch). The exact line that's causing the freezing is the line that tries to open a connection again - the line that begins with $fp = ...